# Markdown problem with preview $ sign in PhpStorm

Tags: markdown, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In PhpStorm `$` gets converted to `\$` in Markdown preview window. How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please follow [IDEA-258796](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258796) for updates